# How to properly serve Angular 6/7 app using node / express?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular7

I'm working on an Angular 7 app, and it is now time to start serving it using node / express.
My index.html is located in the src directory:

```
my_app/src/index.html
```

Here is my server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoDB = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/automon';

mongoose.connect(mongoDB);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var MonitoringInfoSchema = new Schema({
    monitoring_target: String,
    monitoring_description: String,
    resource_name: String,
    monitoring_method: String,
    monitoring_routine: String
});

var MonitoringResultsSchema = new Schema({
    monitoring_target: String,
    monitoring_method: String,
    monitoring_description: String,
    resource_name: String,
    monitoring_routine: String,
    monitoring_result: String,
    result_acknowledged: Boolean,
    date_recorded: Date
});

var LastMonitoringResultsSchema = new Schema({
    monitoring_target: String,
    monitoring_method: String,
    monitoring_description: String,
    resource_name: String,
    monitoring_routine: String,
    monitoring_result: String,
    result_acknowledged: Boolean,
    date_recorded: Date
});

var MonitoringInfo = mongoose.model('MonitoringInfo', MonitoringInfoSchema );

var MonitoringResult = mongoose.model('MonitoringResult', MonitoringResultsSchema );

var LastMonitoringResult = mongoose.model('LastMonitoringResult', LastMonitoringResultsSchema );

const app = express();

//Parsers for POST data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//Point static path to dist
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '.')));

setInterval(function () {
    MonitoringInfo.find({}, function(err, docs) {
        if (!err){


            docs.forEach(function(item){
                var single_doc = item._doc;

                var monitoring_target = single_doc.monitoring_target;
                var monitoring_description = single_doc.monitoring_description;
                var resource_name = single_doc.resource_name;
                var monitoring_method = single_doc.monitoring_method;
                var monitoring_routine = single_doc.monitoring_routine;

                switch (monitoring_method) {

                    ///////////////// DAG Status /////////////////////////////////
                    case 'DAG Status': console.log("DAG Status is our monitoring method");

                        var queryString = 'http://localhost:5000/get_status' + '?target=' + monitoring_target + '&routine=' + monitoring_routine
                            + '&description=' + monitoring_description + '&resource_name=' + resource_name + '&monitoring_method=' + monitoring_method;
                        request(queryString, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
                            if (err) { return console.log(err); }
                            console.log(body.url);
                            // console.log(body.explanation);
                            // return body
                            body.forEach(function(monitoringRecord){
                                var dag_id = monitoringRecord['dag_id'];
                                var target = monitoring_target;
                                var description = monitoring_description;
                                var method = monitoring_method;
                                var monitoringRoutine = monitoring_routine;
                                var resourceName = dag_id;
                                var date = Date.now();

                                var result = JSON.stringify(monitoringRecord);

                                console.log("Monitoring record:  " + monitoringRecord["dag_id"] + "  " +
                                    monitoringRecord["date"] + "  " + monitoringRecord["status"]);

                                //Here, we save the monitoring results to MongoDB history collection
                                var monitoring_result_model_instance = new MonitoringResult(
                                    { monitoring_target: target,
                                        monitoring_method: method,
                                        monitoring_description: description,
                                        resource_name: resourceName,
                                        monitoring_routine: monitoringRoutine,
                                        monitoring_result: result,
                                        result_acknowledged: false,
                                        date_recorded: date
                                    });

                                monitoring_result_model_instance.save(function (err) {
                                    if (err) console.log(err);
                                    else {
                                        s=""
                                    }
                                });

                                var latest_monitoring_result = {
                                    monitoring_target: target,
                                    monitoring_method: method,
                                    monitoring_description: description,
                                    resource_name: resourceName,
                                    monitoring_routine: monitoringRoutine,
                                    monitoring_result: result,
                                    result_acknowledged: false,
                                    date_recorded: date
                                };
                                var query = { 'resource_name':resourceName};
                                LastMonitoringResult.findOneAndUpdate(query, latest_monitoring_result, {upsert:true},function (err, doc) {
                                    if (err) console.log(err);
                                    else {
                                        s=""
                                    }
                                });
                            });

                        });
                        break;

                    //////////// PROCESS VERIFICATION  ///////////////////////////////////

                    case 'Process Verification': console.log("Process Verification is our monitoring method");


                        var processVerificationQueryString = 'http://localhost:5000/process_verification' + '?target=' + monitoring_target + '&routine=' + monitoring_routine
                            + '&description=' + monitoring_description + '&resource_name=' + resource_name + '&monitoring_method=' + monitoring_method;

                        request(processVerificationQueryString, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
                            if (err) { return console.log(err); }

                            console.log(body.url);

                            body.forEach(function(monitoringRecord){
                                var target = monitoring_target;
                                var description = monitoring_description;
                                var method = monitoring_method;
                                var monitoringRoutine = monitoring_routine;
                                var resourceName = monitoringRecord["resource_name"];
                                var date = Date.now();

                                var result = JSON.stringify(monitoringRecord["status"]);

                                console.log("Monitoring record:  " + monitoringRecord["status"] + "  " +
                                    monitoringRecord["date"]);

                                //Here, we save the monitoring results to MongoDB history collection
                                var monitoring_result_model_instance = new MonitoringResult(
                                    { monitoring_target: target,
                                        monitoring_method: method,
                                        monitoring_description: description,
                                        resource_name: resourceName,
                                        monitoring_routine: monitoringRoutine,
                                        monitoring_result:   JSON.stringify({status: JSON.parse(result)}),
                                        result_acknowledged: false,
                                        date_recorded: date
                                    });

                                monitoring_result_model_instance.save(function (err) {
                                    if (err) console.log(err);
                                    else {
                                        s=""
                                    }
                                });

                                var latest_monitoring_result = {
                                    monitoring_target: target,
                                    monitoring_method: method,
                                    monitoring_description: description,
                                    resource_name: resourceName,
                                    monitoring_routine: monitoringRoutine,
                                    monitoring_result: JSON.stringify({status: JSON.parse(result)}),
                                    result_acknowledged: false,
                                    date_recorded: date
                                };
                                var query = { 'resource_name':resourceName};
                                LastMonitoringResult.findOneAndUpdate(query, latest_monitoring_result, {upsert:true},function (err, doc) {
                                    if (err) console.log(err);
                                    else {
                                        s=""
                                    }
                                });
                            });

                        });

                        break;

                    //////////////// REST RESPONSE   ////////////////////////////////
                    case 'REST Response': console.log("REST Response is our monitoring method");

                        var restResponseQueryString = 'http://localhost:5000/rest_response' + '?target=' + monitoring_target + '&routine=' + monitoring_routine
                            + '&description=' + monitoring_description + '&resource_name=' + resource_name + '&monitoring_method=' + monitoring_method;

                        request(restResponseQueryString, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
                            if (err) { return console.log(err); }

                            console.log(body.url);

                            body.forEach(function(monitoringRecord){
                                var target = monitoring_target;
                                var description = monitoring_description;
                                var method = monitoring_method;
                                var monitoringRoutine = monitoring_routine;
                                var resourceName = monitoringRecord["resource_name"];
                                var date = Date.now();

                                var result = JSON.stringify(monitoringRecord["status"]);

                                console.log("Monitoring record:  " + monitoringRecord["status"] + "  " +
                                    monitoringRecord["date"]);

                                //Here, we save the monitoring results to MongoDB history collection
                                var monitoring_result_model_instance = new MonitoringResult(
                                    { monitoring_target: target,
                                        monitoring_method: method,
                                        monitoring_description: description,
                                        resource_name: resourceName,
                                        monitoring_routine: monitoringRoutine,
                                        monitoring_result:   JSON.stringify({status: JSON.parse(result)}),
                                        result_acknowledged: false,
                                        date_recorded: date
                                    });

                                monitoring_result_model_instance.save(function (err) {
                                    if (err) console.log(err);
                                    else {
                                        s=""
                                    }
                                });

                                var latest_monitoring_result = {
                                    monitoring_target: target,
                                    monitoring_method: method,
                                    monitoring_description: description,
                                    resource_name: resourceName,
                                    monitoring_routine: monitoringRoutine,
                                    monitoring_result: JSON.stringify({status: JSON.parse(result)}),
                                    result_acknowledged: false,
                                    date_recorded: date
                                };
                                var query = { 'resource_name':resourceName};
                                LastMonitoringResult.findOneAndUpdate(query, latest_monitoring_result, {upsert:true},function (err, doc) {
                                    if (err) console.log(err);
                                    else {
                                        s=""
                                    }
                                });
                            });

                        });


                        break;
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


                    default: console.log("");
                }
            });

            // process.exit();
        } else {throw err;}
    });

    //THIS IS WHERE YOU CONTROL THE ACTUAL FREQUENCY OF MONITORING CALLS

}, 10000);


// Catch all other routes and return the index file
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
});

app.get('/status', (rq, rs) => {
    request('http://localhost:5000/get_status', { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
        if (err) { return console.log(err); }
        console.log(body.url);
        // console.log(body.explanation);
        // return body
        rs.send(body);
    });

});

app.get('/monitoringresults', (rq, rs) => {

    var results = [];

    LastMonitoringResult.find({}, function(err, docs) {
        if (!err){

            docs.forEach(function(item){
                results.push(item._doc);

            });
            rs.send(results);

        } else {throw err;}
    });

});

app.get('/allmonitoringresults', (rq, rs) => {

    var results = [];

    MonitoringResult.find({}, function(err, docs) {
        if (!err){

            docs.forEach(function(item){
                results.push(item._doc);

            });
            rs.send(results);

        } else {throw err;}
    });

});

app.post('/monitoring_info', function(req, res) {
    var monitoring_target = req.body.target;
    var monitoring_description = req.body.description;
    var resource_name = req.body.resourceName;
    var monitoring_method = req.body.monitoring_method;
    var monitoring_routine = req.body.monitoring_routine;

    var model_instance = new MonitoringInfo({ monitoring_target: monitoring_target, monitoring_method: monitoring_method,
        monitoring_description: monitoring_description, resource_name: resource_name, monitoring_routine: monitoring_routine});

    model_instance.save(function (err) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        else {
            res.sendStatus(201);
        }
    });
});

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
const server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on localhost:${port}`));
```

This server.js file is located in the same src directory:

```
   my_app/src/server.js
```

When I run node server.js, navigate to

```
   localhost:3000/
```

in Chrome, I get a blank page.
When I choose to Inspect it, I get this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Coda - Angular 7 Admin UI Kit</title>
  <base href="/">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/img/favicon.png">
</head>

<body>
  <app>
    <div class="overlay"></div>

    <div class="loader loader-4">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </app>
</body>
</html>
```

I suspect, that something else needs to happen to my Angular code, before it can be properly served / rendered

What do I need to do, in order to have the Angular 7 app rendered?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I had to do, in order to serve my Angular 7 app from node / express:

```
1) run ng build
2) reloacte server.js up one level - to the root dir
3) change the following lines on server.js:

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
...
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});
```